# Using graph api to obtain a direct link on page feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

I have now tried a lot of combinations, but I fail to reproduce the same result as obtained when posting manually:

I want to post a link to a facebook page I have created (not to the user wall). I do this by obtaining the page access token:

```
$page_access = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'?fields=access_token');
```

Then I set (before posting):

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($page_access['access_token']);
```

Finally my post is:

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my link', 
    'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com'
;
$sendMessage = $facebook->api('/'.$pageid.'/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

I have also tried setting the name, link and description fields in the $attachment structure, but the published result always includes a link of the type:

https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=_my_app_id&method=permissions.request&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2F&response_type=code&display=async&auth_referral=1

instead of the direct link to http://www.facebook.com. However, if I post the link manually I get a direct link (this is what I want) and also a "Share" action.

So my question: How do I convince the api to publish the link as is, and also get a "Share" action?

Answer (score 2):

The reason your app is not posting a direct link is because you have `Authenticated Referrals` enabled on your application. This means Facebook always tries to get the user to `Connect` to your links before they are redirected to the link.

Try disabling `Authenticated Referrals` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you refer to "Authenticated Referrals" in the Auth Dialog Setup? This is where I set the extended permissions (manage_pages,publish_stream, read_stream) so I can not deactivate it?

Comment: Below the Auth Dialog stuff, there is a secondary setup for `Authenticated Referrals`. Clicking the 'x' in the top-right corner will remove this for you.